# Whats a double asterisk doing in a map function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been reading [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swinginc/react-redux-typescript-into-the-better-frontend-tutorial-d32f46e97995) on how to use react & redux with typescript. The author is normalizing his data using this line of code:

```
return {
  ...state,
  state: 'LOADED',
  notes: action.notes*.map((n: NoteModel) => n.id**)*,
};
```

and I'm trying to understand what the map function is doing.

It's supposed to generate an array of `NoteModel`s  `id`s but I do not understand what all the asterisks are doing there. I thought maybe this is using the ES6 Generator pattern, but I could not find a way to write generators using `**`.

Is this just a typo by the author or is this actual syntax?

Comment: I guess author just used to syntax highlight when wrapping text into asterisk makes it bold. note that in pretty similar case below that positron there is no asterisks.

Comment: @skyboyer Maybe, I would only expect that to be in the *text content*, not a *code snippet*... perhaps just a typo

Comment: @CertainPerformance that's what confused me too. Why would you add this to an actual code-snippet on github? Especially if the code is so straightforward.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author?  The bottom of the article has the author's contact information via Twitter and Github.  Since he published an article, I'm sure he would be happy to explain.